# How to get information on who deleted an s3 resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, blame

I have a bucket that had some files in it. One of them is now gone. How can I get information about who deleted it or when it was deleted--can I get any information at all about this deleted item?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to "who did what?" with AWS APIs is [AWS CloudTrail](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudtrail/).

Specifically, see [Logging Amazon S3 API Calls by Using AWS CloudTrail](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cloudtrail-logging.html).

Also, related to the specific problem of someone deleting an object from S3, 
be aware of a feature of S3 known as [versioning](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/Versioning.html). With versioning, you can easily recover from accidental overwrites or deletions as well as application failures.